# IOS Swift In app purchase - [SKProductsRequest _handleReply:]_block_invoke

Tags: ios, swift3, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I receive the following error in Xcode Crashes reports for my app when a user tries to purchase an item.
From what I see the error is not a general one as some users can buy an item while some cannot from what I see.

```
libobjs.A.dylib      objc_msgSend
StoreKit             __34-[SKProductsRequest_handleReply:]_block_invoke
libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_call_block_and_release
libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_client_callout
libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
```

My code is below.
I really cannot understand where the error can come. Anyone has any idea ?

Thanks,
Bogdan

```
 @IBAction func unlockRemoveAds(_ sender: Any) {
        purchaseMyProduct(product: iapProducts[3])
}


    @IBAction func unlockExtraLessons(_ sender: Any) {
        purchaseMyProduct(product: iapProducts[0])
    }


    @IBAction func unlockExtraTests(_ sender: Any) {
        purchaseMyProduct(product: iapProducts[1])
    }


    @IBAction func unlockFullPackageDeal(_ sender: Any) {
        purchaseMyProduct(product: iapProducts[2])
    }


    @IBAction func restorePurchaseButt(_ sender: Any) {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }


    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        nonConsumablePurchaseMade = true
        UserDefaults.standard.set(nonConsumablePurchaseMade, forKey: "nonConsumablePurchaseMade")

        UIAlertView(title: "Grammar PRO!",
                    message: "You've successfully restored your purchase!",
                    delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
    }


    func fetchAvailableProducts()  {


        let productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects:
         removeAds,
         extraLessonsDeal,
         extraTestsDeal,
         fullPackageDeal
        )


        print(productIdentifiers)
        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
    }



    func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {
        if (response.products.count > 0) {
            iapProducts = response.products

            // Remove Ads Deal
            let removeAdsDeal = response.products[3] as SKProduct

            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
            numberFormatter.locale = removeAdsDeal.priceLocale
            categ1Price.text = numberFormatter.string(from: removeAdsDeal.price)


            // ExtraLessonDeal
            let ExtraLessonDeal = response.products[0] as SKProduct

            numberFormatter.locale = ExtraLessonDeal.priceLocale
            categ2Price.text = numberFormatter.string(from: ExtraLessonDeal.price)

            // ExtraTestDeal
            let ExtraTestDeal = response.products[1] as SKProduct

            numberFormatter.locale = ExtraTestDeal.priceLocale
            categ3Price.text = numberFormatter.string(from: ExtraTestDeal.price)

            // FullPackageDeal
            let FullPackageDeal = response.products[2] as SKProduct

            numberFormatter.locale = FullPackageDeal.priceLocale
            categ4Price.text = numberFormatter.string(from: FullPackageDeal.price)


        }
    }

    // MARK: - MAKE PURCHASE OF A PRODUCT
    func canMakePurchases() -> Bool {  return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()  }

    func purchaseMyProduct(product: SKProduct) {
        if self.canMakePurchases() {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

            print("PRODUCT TO PURCHASE: \(product.productIdentifier)")
            productID = product.productIdentifier
            print(productID)

            // IAP Purchases dsabled on the Device
        } else {
            UIAlertView(title: "Sorry!",
                        message: "Purchases are disabled in your device!",
                        delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
        }
    }



    // MARK:- IAP PAYMENT QUEUE
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        //print("add paymnet")
        //print(extraLessonsDeal)
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
               // print(trans.error)
                switch trans.transactionState {

                case .purchased:



                    if productID == removeAds {

                        print("remove ads")
                        e_1_dbhelper.updateNoAds()
                        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

                        UIAlertView(title: "Thank you for your purchase :-)",
                                    message: "You've successfully removed ads!",
                                    delegate: nil,
                                    cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
                        let secondViewController:UIViewController = a_1_meniu()
                        self.present(secondViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)


                    }
               else if productID == "com.labsterzz.extraLessonsDeal" {

                        print("extra lessons")
                        e_1_dbhelper.updateNoAds()
                        e_1_dbhelper.updateExtraLessons()
                   SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)


                        UIAlertView(title: "Thank you for your purchase :-)",
                                    message: "You've successfully unlocked Extra Lessons Deal!",
                                    delegate: nil,
                                    cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()

                        let secondViewController:UIViewController = b_2_learning()
                        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondViewController)
                        self.present(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)

                    }
              else if productID == extraTestsDeal {

                        print("extra tests")
                        e_1_dbhelper.updateNoAds()
                        e_1_dbhelper.updateExtraTests()
                       SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)


                        UIAlertView(title: "Thank you for your purchase :-)",
                                    message: "You've successfully unlocked Extra Tests Deal!",
                                    delegate: nil,
                                    cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()

                        let secondViewController:UITableViewController = b_1_choose_test()
                        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondViewController)
                        self.present(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)

                    }
               else if productID == fullPackageDeal {

                        print("full package")
                        e_1_dbhelper.updateNoAds()
                        e_1_dbhelper.updateExtraLessons()
                        e_1_dbhelper.updateExtraTests()
                        e_1_dbhelper.updateFullPackage()
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

                        UIAlertView(title: "Thank you for your purchase :-)",
                                    message: "You've successfully unlocked Full Package Deal!",
                                    delegate: nil,
                                    cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
                        let secondViewController:UIViewController = a_1_meniu()
                        self.present(secondViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

                    }

                  //  SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                  //  break;

                case .failed:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .restored:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .deferred:
                    break
                case .purchasing:
                    break
                default:
                    print((transaction.transactionState.rawValue))
                }}}
    }
```

Comment: do you solve this issue ? I just got the same on my app after pushed an update. Works fine on sandbox environnement. Crash on prod ...